# error "429" AcitveX Component Can't create object (in vb6)

Tags: vb.net, vb6, activex, com-interop

I have one problem in vb6. I created a .tlb file in VB.net 2005 by adding Com class to project. I built the project, I got .tlb file and .dll files while building project, i selected "Register for Com interop" from project properties and built. It registered autometically and I can use created .tlb file in that PC in Vb6 working fine. if I deploy application to another PC and run I am getting "Error 429 ActiveX Component Can't create object" run time error. What I need to do? Please help me as soon as possible. I can't deploy the application to client due to above error.

one possible solution is to install .net frame work on client pc i never want to install .net framework any other solution will be most appreciatable.

Comment: dlls made in Net, need the Net Framework on the client PC, There is no avoiding that.

Answer (score 6):

If you've created a DLL in a .NET language (such as VB.NET), the target computer *must* have the .NET Framework installed in order to use the DLL.

This a hard and fast requirement, irrelevant of how you're utilizing the DLL, whether from a VB 6 application through COM interop or otherwise. It is also a hurdle you'll have to jump over first, before you worry about things like registering COM components, as [Uday's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9652565/366904) suggests.

If you don't want a dependency on .NET, you need to use another environment to create the ActiveX DLL; either C++ or VB 6 are possible choices.

Answer (score -1):

One option may be that, while deployment, you need to register that .tlb file in System Registry using regsvr32 command in command-prompt. Generally static libraries does not work until they are registered with System Registry.
You might have seen many programs register components during installation like 'Registering Type Components' or 'Registering COM Components' (for those who do networking especially). Those components are nothing but native COM dlls and tlbs. 
so when creating deployment project, add some scripting login to register thode dlls and tlb to System registry using:

```
regsvr32 <path to tlb/dll>
```

you have to recursivey call this command for every dll/tlb you want to register with system. For example, if you have 4 dlls and 2 tlbs then you have to call it 6 times providing the path of dll and tlb one at a time.

Comment: i trying  to register .dlls message show the DllRegisterServer entry point was not found but tlb file successfully registered

Comment: does your tlb has any dependencies over other dlls/tlbs? What OS you are running? and are you deploying the reight version of tlb that you are using in development environment?

Comment: @user757321: you yourself has answered. every dll needs to have this function. This is the starting point in a DLL.

Comment: i m using windows xp on both system.regasm.exe tool to register .net dlls .but problem is i never want to install .net framework on client pc any other tool register .net dlls. if i install .net framework its working

Comment: Yes, it has a dependency on the .NET Framework because it was created in VB.NET. You have to have the .NET Framework installed in order to use it.

Comment: if dlls are created in .net then u do not requrie to register in system registry...

Comment: @CodyGray: i was not aware before that he is using .net. I thought he is creatign dlls usign vb6 only. well, by this fact, you cannot use a .net dll in a vb6 application until the dll is marked with COM attributes. but if u still needs to. then convenient way is to recreate the dll in vb6 as a separate project and refer it to your vb6 project

Comment: The question is a bit unclear, but he does say he used VB.NET 2005. And he did indicate that the DLL should be registered for COM interop, but that doesn't solve the root problem. He wants to run it on a machine *without* the .NET Framework installed. That isn't going to work; .NET libraries require .NET.

Comment: yes i agree with you... but he wants to use it in vb6 which is quite not possible until the user installs .net. well anyhow, if the user has dependency on .net anywhere in his program, then he must install .net on the target machine

Comment: There are no "static libraries" involved here either.  Static libraries are linked as part of a build process, which is what is static about them.